How are azimuthal equidistant projections, specifically of the Earth's total surface area, made?
For some reason I can't find any visualization online as to how azimuthal equidistant projections of the totality of a sphere are made.  The map I'm thinking of specifically is where all of earth is on a flat disc, and say the point at the South Pole is expanded-out to a ring at the boundary of the disc, which hopefully is shown below. I see lots of visualizations of how to do it for hemispheres, but it's not clear to me what goes on after the equator for a whole sphere.  I know stereographic projection is the same as inversion, what is an azimuthal projection considered?


Is this sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_azimuthal_projections.svg  If not, what is missing?  (There is no standing in 3-space watching rays fly from some point through the Earth onto a surface that can make this projection, so what's missing from the linked image?)

For each point on the spherical Earth, find its distance and direction from the centre (the north pole in this example), then plot using polar coordinates. This is the same procedure both inside or outside the equator. (Except the antipode.)

@EricTowers yes I saw that image you linked to, but there's that ambiguous box around the azimuthal image so I wasn't clear if it correlated to one of the tiny earths above to show how the rays work.  Are you saying there's no direct way to visualize the mapping from 3D space? thanks

@peterwhy I think I understand that for the northern hemisphere projecting onto a disc, but what do you do once you pass the equator as you continue to go south?  thanks

Each of the little Earths above correspond to the tiny maps immediately below each of them.  The Definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection#Definition shows that the rays are not "sane" in 3-space and the Animated Lambert Projections there show how rays have to move nonlinearly.  The "equidistant" version requires that the circles closer to the south pole are moved further away from the center than in equal-area (as shown in my first linked image) so that distance from the map center is proportional to the change in latitude from the north pole.

Still, for each location in the southern hemisphere, find its (great circle) distance and direction from the north pole. Such distance is along a line of longitude from the north pole to that location.

@EricTowers That cross section image with curved arcs and the animations are very helpful and make more sense now... I suppose my confusion was thinking that azimuthal projections used straight rays like stereographic, but instead it looks like it's a bit more complicated than that.  So all azimuthal projections are like this, not just Lambert's version?  There are images online like this one that seem to imply azimuthal is linear, but it's not mathematically correct?: https://blog.bellerbyandco.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Cartography_Maps.png

There are azimuthal projections that project along straight rays.  The azimuthal equidistant and Labmert azimuthal equal-area do not.  One thing I notice about your new image link is that it either projects both hemispheres onto a disk "two points to one" (the left diagram) or you only get one hemisphere.

@EricTowers thank you, is there a name or adjective for those azimuthals that do use straight rays?

I don't think you'll find a consistent term for this.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuthal_projection#Azimuthal_(projections_onto_a_plane) suggests "perspective projections" but I don't know of a projection that incorporates this information in its name.

Here's an animation loop showing how 1/4 of the globe "unwraps" (with the remaining 3/4 shown as static slices): https://i.sstatic.net/BH1wtxwz.gif
